# Getting the pixel area of the individual changes (Change Detection Map) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to get the change pixel area from the change detection map. As in bareland-waterbody, bareland-builtup, bareland-vegetation, vegetation-vegetation, vegetation-builtup, vegetation-waterbody etc. 
Below is the link to the script:
   https://code.earthengine.google.com/5037318a76283385a9c217f3cb610fa8

```
//Imported image

 var changeDetection = image2;
 Map.addLayer(changeDetection,
{min: 0, max: 11, palette: ['green', 'wheat', 'blue', 'red', 'white', 'pink', 'orange', 'black', 
'brown', 'yellow']},'changeDetection8616');

//Shapefile

var densu = Densu;

//Classified image 1986

// Select the class from the classified image

 var veg = classified86.select('classification').eq(0);
 Map.addLayer(veg);

// Calculate the pixel area in square kilometer

var area_veg = veg.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

// Reducing the statistics for study area

 var stat = area_veg.reduceRegion ({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
 geometry: Densu,
 scale: 30,
 maxPixels: 1e9,
 });

// Get the sq km area for vegetation

print('Vegetation Area(in sq.km)', stat);

// Select the class from the classified image

var water = classified86.select('classification').eq(1);
Map.addLayer(water);

// Calculate the pixel area in square kilometer

var area_water = water.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

// Reducing the statistics for study area

var stat1 = area_water.reduceRegion ({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: Densu,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
});

// Get the sq km area for waterbody

print('Waterbody Area(in sq.km)', stat1);

// Select the class from the classified image

var bare = classified86.select('classification').eq(2);
Map.addLayer(bare);

// Calculate the pixel area in square kilometer

var area_bare = bare.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

// Reducing the statistics for study area

var stat2 = area_bare.reduceRegion ({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: Densu,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9,
});

// Get the sq km area for bareland

print('Bareland Area(in sq.km)', stat2);

//List of the individual values in km2

var sample = ee.Array([stat.values().get(0), stat1.values().get(0), stat2.values().get(0)]) ;
print([stat.values().get(0), stat1.values().get(0), stat2.values().get(0)], 'sample');

//Classified image 2016
// Select the class from the classified image 

var veg3 = classified16.select('classification').eq(0);
Map.addLayer(veg3);

// Calculate the pixel area in square kilometer
var area_veg3 = veg3.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

// Reducing the statistics for study area

var stat3 = area_veg3.reduceRegion ({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: Densu,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9,
});

// Get the sq km area for vegetation

print('Vegetation Area(in sq.km)', stat3);

// Select the class from the classified image

var water4 = classified16.select('classification').eq(2);
Map.addLayer(water4);

// Calculate the pixel area in square kilometer

var area_water4 = water4.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

// Reducing the statistics for study area

var stat4 = area_water4.reduceRegion ({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: Densu,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
});

// Get the sq km area for Waterbody
print('Waterbody Area(in sq.km)', stat4);

// Select the class from the classified image

var builtup = classified16.select('classification').eq(3);
Map.addLayer(builtup);

// Calculate the pixel area in square kilometer
var area_builtup = builtup.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

// Reducing the statistics for study area

var stat5 = area_builtup.reduceRegion ({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: Densu,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9,
});

// Get the sq km area for Builtup

 print('Builtup Area(in sq.km)', stat5);

//List of the individual class in km2

 var sample1 = ee.Array([stat3.values().get(0), stat4.values().get(0), stat5.values().get(0)]) ;
 print([stat3.values().get(0), stat4.values().get(0), stat5.values().get(0)], 'sample1');
```

Comment: Did you get this error message? `changeDetection8616: Layer error: Image.load: Image asset 'users/edwinosei1995/DENSUw' not found.`

Comment: No i did not get any message of that nature.

Comment: New link to the script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/512aa600baff4e60533ad8d759e85a33